# System.Random producing the same random number

Tags: random, f#

Despite the Random generator only being created once, the output is always the same random result (for all three test outputs).

A test snippet from a slightly larger script:

```
   let myRandGen = System.Random()
   let getRandomObject = 
      let options = [|"Bob"; "Jim"; "Jane"|]
      let randIndex  = myRandGen.Next(options.Length) 
      options.[randIndex] 

   printfn "New one: %s" getRandomObject
   printfn "New two: %s" getRandomObject
   printfn "New three: %s" getRandomObject
```

I need the output to be random for each call, which it currently isn't.

Example output:

```
New one: Jane
New two: Jane
New three: Jane
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `getRandomObject` is a value. It is evaluated once. To fix this, make `getRandomObject` a function:

```
let getRandomObject () = 
  let options = [|"Bob"; "Jim"; "Jane"|]
  let randIndex  = myRandGen.Next(options.Length) 
  options.[randIndex]
```

and call it like so: `getRandomObject ()`

Comment: Thanks you, This makes sense but I'm now getting a squiggly line under the "options.[randIndex]" saying; "The result of this expression has type 'string' and is implicitly ignored.". I don't understand the issue as I thought the function would be unit -> string (in fact it's unit -> 'a)

Comment: The type of getRandomObject  id unit -> string. I would guess you have an indentation problem somewhere. Maybe check the indentation of "printfn "New one: %s" (getRandomObject ())" (or whatever comes after "options.[randIndex]")

Comment: On a side note, be aware that if you run this function in a tight loop, you might get results that are not randomly distributed, since the entropy (or rather the values used to calculate it) does not change/refill fast enough. Always plan to use a slight delay between calls.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel Wait, what? For sure the PRNG is deterministic... I mean, you can provide a seed to always get the same sequence. Or is this not the case here? (I didn't test it...)

Comment: I've run into issues where you exhaust the entropy with a tight loop and subsequently the system is not able to reproduce new values fast enough. I have not tested it with F#'s RNG, though.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel: No, System.Random() is deterministic. It has *no entropy* at all after the initial seed. Delays between calls do nothing, the same value is returned either way.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
   let myRandGen = System.Random()
   let getRandomObject () = 
      let options = [|"Bob"; "Jim"; "Jane"|]
      let randIndex  = myRandGen.Next(options.Length) 
      options.[randIndex] 

   printfn "New one: %s" (getRandomObject())
   printfn "New two: %s" (getRandomObject())
   printfn "New three: %s" (getRandomObject())
```

Comment: I didn't realize that that function calls like that needed to be parenthesized. Thank you very much Scott - it works! ~

Comment: Yeah, the parentheses are required because without them the compiler doesn't know if () is an argument to getRandomObject or to printfn. In F#, the () means a value of type unit, which is similar to void in other languages. If you don't like the parentheses, you could use the back pipe operator <| instead, but F#'s creator, Don Syme, discourages the use of that operator because it's less readable. The forward pipe |> , on the other hand, is widely used to show the flow of data through a series of functions.

Answer (score 0):

You generated your random number once, which doesn't change throughout the whole program. To have a new random value after every use, you must re-initialize the random value.

Comment: `myRandGen` is  a random generator, not a random value, and doesn't need to be reinitialized.